# BigQuery scheduled queries - Create table and add date suffix to its name in a different project

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, scheduled-tasks, project

According to the documentation, (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#destination_table) the same project must be used when defining a destination for a scheduled query.

However, I'd like to schedule a query with the capability to write tables during the query steps to other projects (e.g., CREATE TABLE `xxx.dataset.name_{run_date}`) and to preserve the {run_date} as a suffix. Is it possible to do that in BQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a limitation of Google BigQuery. A workaround could consist of scheduling a query without a specific destination table in the UI and executing the query dynamically, i.e.,

```
DECLARE my_table_name STRING;
SET my_table_name = other_project.my_table_ || CURRENT_DATE();

--- Create the table with the desired table name  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || my_table_name || ' AS SELECT * FROM `xxx` ';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in **BigQuery UI**. A possible workaround is to use **BigQuery [Python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#python) Client Library** as shown below code:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
from datetime import date

today = date.today() #use to replicate @run_date parameter
str_today = str(today).replace("-", "")

transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()

# The project where the query job runs is the same as the project
# containing the destination dataset.
project_id = "your-project-id"
dataset_id = "your-source-dataset-id"

# This service account will be used to execute the scheduled queries. Omit
# this request parameter to run the query as the user with the credentials
# associated with this client.
service_account_name = "your-service-account"

# Use standard SQL syntax for the query.
query_string = f"CREATE TABLE destination-project.destination-dataset.new_table_{str_today} AS (SELECT column FROM source-project.source-dataset.source-table);"

parent="projects/your-project-id/locations/us-central1" #change location accordingly

transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer.TransferConfig(
    name="projects/your-project-id/locations/us-central1/transferConfigs", #change location accordingly
    display_name="Test Schedule",
    data_source_id="scheduled_query",
    params={
        "query": query_string,
    },
    schedule="every 24 hours",
)

transfer_config = transfer_client.create_transfer_config(
    bigquery_datatransfer.CreateTransferConfigRequest(
        parent=parent,
        transfer_config=transfer_config,
        service_account_name=service_account_name,
    )
)

print("Created scheduled query '{}'".format(transfer_config.name))
```

My sample output table:
[image]

Comment: Does the comment ''The project where the query job runs is the same as the project
 containing the destination dataset'' mean that the same limitation is found with the API?

Comment: Yes. But if you use CREATE TABLE syntax on your scheduled query and then explicitly define the another project's dataset on it, it can be a workaround as shown on the code above. You may try it